# Error in retrieving values from SQlite DB from phoneGap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

```
function populateDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(course TEXT, grade INTEGER)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Geography, World",90)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Health",92)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Literature, English",91)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Math 201",85)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Science 202",95)');
}

function queryDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test',[],querrySuccess,errorCB);
}

function querrySuccess(tx,results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length;
    alert("test TABLE: "+ len +"row(s) found");
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        console.log("Row = " + i + " COURSE = " + results.rows.item(i).course + " GRADE =  " + results.rows.item(i).grade);
    }
}

function errorCB(err)
{
    alert("Error processing SQL"+err.code);
}

function successCB()
{
    alert("Success!");
}

function create_database()
{
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database","1.0", "Demo DB", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB,errorCB,successCB);
    db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
}
```

In the above code, i am creating a new database called test. the function create_database() is called when my html form loads. My question is, it is showing the alert for displaying the number of rows, but then it gives an alert "Error processing SQL" i.e it is redirected to the errorCB function. Y so? am i doing nethn wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will look closer to your code, but first of all you don't have any primary key in your table. Maybe you could test something like :

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, course TEXT, grade INTEGER)"
```

Comment: for wat? the code that i pasted is just a sample code, i just wanted to see how the database integration works with PhoneGap, and i tried doing what u have suggested. it just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's because `db.transaction` calls are asynchronously. You're trying to read from the database before the previous transaction to create table and insert data are completed. You should fire the second transaction after the first one finished

Answer (score 0):

```
use in callback function like this.

tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, course TEXT, grade INTEGER)",[], function (tx, results) {
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Geography, World",90)');
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Health",92)');
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Literature, English",91)');
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Math 201",85)');
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(course,grade) VALUES ("Science 202",95)');

       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test',[],function(result){


       },function(error) {
           alert("erorr..." + error);
       });
});
```